# How to add URL parameters from a NameValuePair to the HttpPost request

Tags: java, android, api

I am trying to make a request to a `webApi` url, u have written the following code and i have my parameters in a `NameValuePair` object.

Now i don't know how to add these parameters to the base uri do i have to do it manually by concatenating strings? or is there any other way, please help.

```
private static final String apiBaseUri="http://myapp.myweb.com/path?";

private boolean POST(List<NameValuePair>[] nameValuePairs){
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(apiBaseUri); 
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs[0]));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    String respond = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
    Log.d("MSG 3 > ",respond);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this to add the parameters to the url

```
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",value));
  String UrlString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8");

   url +=UrlString;
```